# Why is the steady speed neglected when calculating work or power?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, power

> A driver notices that her 1080-kg car, when in neutral, slows down from 95 km/hr to 65 km/hr in about 7.0s on a flat horizontal road. Approximately what power (watts and hp) is needed to keep the car traveling at a constant 80 km/h?

Here's what I did, I calculated the energy I would need to oppose the 95-65 change and then I added the energy needed to move at 80 km/hr then I divided by 7 . I think I have a misconception + a mistake somewhere because the book's answer is different. Can someone tell me where I went wrong ?

P.s, I know I can calculate the acceleration and then use F=ma AND F=PV but I don't understand why the work isn't energy needed to oppose 95-65 + KE for V=80. 
If you know, please answer I have been trying to understand this for 6 hours.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The other answers are correct, I just want to try a different wording to see if it clears it up.

> "Here's what I did, I calculated the energy I would need to oppose the 95-65 change **and then I added the energy needed to move at 80 km/hr** then I divided by 7 . "

Emphasis mine.  **No** energy is needed for the car to keep moving at $80 \ kph$ if there were no resisting force.  If the car is already at $80 \ kph$, the energy needed to maintain that speed only depends on the force resisting the movement.

The kinetic energy required is $$\Delta KE = \frac 12 m v_{1}^2 - \frac 12 m v_0^2$$ and since $v_0 = v_1 = 80 \ kph$, $\Delta KE = 0$. You only need to look at the energy required to overcome the resistance; because besides that, the object will want to maintain the $80 \ kph$.

Comment: Shouldn't the fact that the the speed is 80 km/h and not some other speed matter for the power though?

Comment: @AaronStevens Yes, it will have an effect on power to oppose resisting force, but OP was saying "+ the KE for V=80" which made me think that was what confused him.  I think he tried to add on the KE of an object moving 80 kph; but that doesn't make sense when you consider that it's already at that speed.

Comment: Right. The weird thing is that the answer by TheLastAirbender has the answer as $\Delta K/t$ for the 95 km/h to the 65 km/h over the 7 seconds, which does give the right answer without even considering the 80 km/h... I think it might just be a coincidence. I don't think in general that the average power during the slow down is equal to the power to maintain any constant speed.

Comment: I don't think so. Their answer says the power is equal to $\Delta K/t$

Comment: @AaronStevens Nevermind I think you're right about that.  It seems pretty strange here that it gets the right answer, but I think I see why.  Because the average of 95 and 65 is 80, the average change in KE over the 7 second window would be exactly the same as the power required to maintain the speed at 80 kph with that dissipation.  I'm not sure if averaging the dissipative force like that actually makes sense though... but I had to make that assumption when solving in the P = Fv method anyways.

Comment: Yeah exactly... I think it makes more sense to find the average force and then multiply by the 80 km/h. It doesn't make sense that the average power during the slow down is the answer in general. I think it is just a coincidence here... I will edit my answer.

Comment: Unless....what if you assumed that the dissipative force's magnitude depended on velocity?

Comment: @AaronStevens I sketched out the math, and you can kinda see why they're both the same.  In our method, you have average force, which is difference in velocity over time times mass; and then you times that all by velocity.  In the KE method, you can change $(v_1^2 - v_0^2)$ to $(v_1 - v_0)(v_1 + v_0)$,  $(v_1 - v_0)$ gives the velocity difference from our method, and $\frac {(v_1 + v_0)}{2}$ gives you 80 kph (the average); where we get the half from the $\frac 12$ in KE; and then he divides by $t$ and multiplies by $m$ as well.  I'm not sure if it's meaningful or coincidence.